# Как убрать переворот изображения при масштабировании React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент диаграмма, размер которого я увеличиваю и уменьшаю. Когда размер становится максимально маленьким, диаграмма переворачивается и обратно увеличивается. Не могу понять, почему это происходит и как устранить эту проблему.

```
export const Diagram = () => {
const [areaPosition, setAreaPosition] = useState({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        scale: 1
    });
const updateXarrow = useXarrow();

    const onMouseWheelZoom = (event) => {
        updateXarrow();
        event.preventDefault();
        const factor = 0.5;
        const delta = event.deltaY / 120;
        const newScale = areaPosition.scale + delta * factor;

        const ratio = 1 - newScale / areaPosition.scale;
        setAreaPosition({
            scale: newScale,
            x: areaPosition.x + (event.clientX - areaPosition.x) * ratio,
            y: areaPosition.y + (event.clientY - areaPosition.y) * ratio,
        });
    };
return (
        <div className={styles.MainContainer}>
            <VerticalMenu
                diagram={diagram}
                onChangeDiagram={onChangeDiagramHandler}
                selectedDiagramType={selectedDiagramType}
                setSelectedDiagramType={setSelectedDiagramType}
            />
            <div
                className={styles.AreaContainer}
                onWheelCapture={onMouseWheelZoom}
            >
                <div className={styles.ClassesContainer}>
                    <Xwrapper>
                        <div
                            style={{
                                transformOrigin: "0 0",
                                transform: `translate(${areaPosition.x}px, ${areaPosition.y}px) scale(${areaPosition.scale})`
                            }}
                        >
                            {getTables()}
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.ArrowContainer}>
                            {getArrows()}
                        </div>
                    </Xwrapper>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Как отредактировать функцию onMouseWheelZoom, чтобы не было этого поворота?

Comment: Реакт сам ничего не переворачивает. Может у вас какая библиотека это делает?

Comment: выведи значение `scale`. Посмотри в какой момент он становится отрицательным.

Comment: @SwaD Не уверена. Скорее, я что-то в уравнении про трансформации не так написала, но не могу понять, что именно. Раньше диаграмма уменьшалась и исчезала. Я поставила ограничение: значение factor было 0.1, я заменила на 0.5. Исчезать изображение перестало, но получился такой поворот

Comment: @Grundy в тот момент, когда она переворачивается, scale отрицательный. А как это изменить? Почему это происходит?

Comment: меняй расчет `const newScale = areaPosition.scale + delta * factor;` как минимум можешь `Math.abs` добавить. Либо устанавливать в 0 если стало меньше 0

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Это помогло!)

Comment: @Grundy правда, она сначала немного увеличивается, а потом снова уменьшается. И так скачет, когда до минимума доходит. Это как-то можно устранить?

Comment: _Либо устанавливать в 0 если стало меньше 0_: `Math.max(0, areaPosition.scale + delta * factor)`